# Problemas com Request utilizando superagent

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Estou tentando realizar um `request` utilizando a biblioteca [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) no meu servidor `nodejs`, estou seguindo a documentação, porém, não está funcionando. Segue meu código `nodejs`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('superagent');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5006));    

request
   .get('http://www.google.com.br')
   .end(function(err, res){

   });

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Segue o link da documentação do `superagent`:

http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#request-basics

Alguém poderia me ajudar no que estou errando neste `request` ?

Comment: Qual é o problema? testei e funciona bem. Coloca `console.log(err, res.text);` dentro desse `.end(function(err, res){`

Comment: @Sergio, minha dúvida é, após receber o conteúdo `res.text`, ao invés de exibir no `console.log`, é possível exibir no browser a página html requisitada? Exemplo, nesse trecho, eu requisitei  a página do google através do meu servidor `nodejs` e gostaria de exibi-la no browser e não no console.

Comment: @Sergio, consegui, acrescentei esse trecho de código `app.get('/', function(req, resp) {
 request
   .get('http://www.google.com.br')
   .end(function(err, res){
  //console.log(err, res.text);
  enviar = res.text;
  console.log(enviar);
  resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html, application/json; charset=utf-8' });
  resp.end(res.text);
   }); 
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar assim:

```
app.get('/', function(req, resp) {
    request("http://www.google.com.br", function(err, res){ 
        resp.send(res.body);
    });
});
```

Quando usas o [`resp.send(res.body);`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) o Express adiciona automaticamente os HTTP headers e não precisas de fazer isso separado.

Comment: com o `body` o meu não funcionou, com ele aparece `{ }`. Quando uso o `text` aparece certo.

Comment: @Duds acho que depende se estás a usar sintaxe `request().get().end()` ou passando argumentos como eu fiz.